# Ubuntu 18.04 freezes on boot

Tags: boot, nvidia, 18.04

I know a lot of questions have been asked like this, but none of them are the exact situation as me.

I am on a Dell XPS 15 9560 running a Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.04 dual boot.  The Ubuntu 18.04 OS will boot sometimes, but occasionally it will freeze on the Ubuntu splash screen with the 5 dots.  When I turn the splash screen off, I notice it freezes right after the line "Started User Manager for UID 121."  I check the `journalctl`, but the logs seem to flush before the problem occurs, and never after, so the actual cause of the issue is never written to the logs.

I have NVIDIA drivers installed, as well as bumblebee.  The kernel options set are currently "nouveau.modeset=0".  I will provide any other information about my system if needed.